# Filtering products from multiple url parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'll try to keep it as short as possible but still trying to keep it simple.

I'm creating an ecommerce site using Next.js and Shopify. This website has products and should be able to filter the products from some attributes. I get products from the Shopify API, These products have Product types and I would like to filter these Product Types with checkboxes.

My version so far has some checkboxes which use the Nextjs useRouter hook to send the checkbox values as url parameters, i then use the url parameters to filter my products array.

So i have two problems, first, i do not know how to push to the url multiple values of the same parameter, for example like this:

```
https://example.com/products?productType=computer&productType=electronics
```

I have only been able to do it like this:

```
https://example.com/products?productType=computer
```

And for question number two, I do not know how to filter from multiple url parameters. I have only managed to filter from one url parameter at a time.

This is the products page which i get my data which i send to my components.

```
   import { shopifyClient, parseShopifyResponse } from "/lib/shopify"
import Link from "next/link"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ProductList from "/components/Products/ProductList"
import ProductFilter from "/components/Products/ProductFilter"
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const getAllProducts = await shopifyClient.product.fetchAll()
    const products = parseShopifyResponse(getAllProducts)

    // const getCollections = await shopifyClient.collection.fetchAllWithProducts()
    // const collections = parseShopifyResponse(getCollections)
    // const getFilteredCollections = collections.filter(
    //  (v, i, a) => a.findIndex((v2) => v2.productType === v.productType) === i
    // )

    return {
        props: {
            collections: getFilteredCollections,
            products: products,
        },
    }
}

export default function ProductsPage({ products, collections }) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { maxPrice, minPrice, productType } = router.query

    if (maxPrice) {
        products = products.filter((product) => {
            return (
                (product.variants[0].price.amount <= Number(maxPrice)) &
                (product.variants[0].price.amount >= Number(minPrice))
            )
        })
    }
    if (minPrice) {
        products = products.filter((product) => {
            return product.variants[0].price.amount >= Number(minPrice)
        })
    }
    if (productType) {
        products = products.filter((product) => {
            return product.productType === productType
        })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <main className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-4">
                <div className="filter">
                    <ProductFilter products={products} />
                </div>
                <div className="products col-span-1 lg:col-span-4">
                    <ProductList products={products} />
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

And this is my filtering component:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRouter, useEffect } from "next/router"
export default function ProductFilter({ products }) {
const [queryParam, setQueryParam] = useState("")
const router = useRouter()

const { productType } = router.query

function handleMinimumPriceQuery() {
    router.query.minPrice = event.target.value
    router.push(router)
}
function handleMaximumPriceQuery() {
    router.query.maxPrice = event.target.value
    router.push(router)
}
function handleProductTypeQuery() {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox")
        console.log(event)

        router.query.productType = event.target.value
        router.push(router)
    } else {
        delete router.query.productType
        router.push(router)
    }
}

const getFilteredProductTypes = products.filter(
    (v, i, a) => a.findIndex((v2) => v2.productType === v.productType) === i
)

return (
    <aside>
        <form className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 pr-4">
                <div className="flex flex-col">
                    <label htmlFor="priceMin">Minimum Price</label>
                    <input
                        className="border p-1 flex flex-1 checkbox"
                        type="number"
                        id="priceMin"
                        placeholder="$0"
                        onChange={handleMinimumPriceQuery}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col">
                    <label htmlFor="priceMax">Maximum Price</label>
                    <input
                        className="border p-1 flex flex-1 checkbox"
                        type="number"
                        id="priceMax"
                        onChange={handleMaximumPriceQuery}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="productTypes">
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <input
                        className="checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="productType"
                        id="Portfolio"
                        value="Portfolio"
                        onChange={handleProductTypeQuery}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="Portfolio">Portfolio</label>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <input
                        className="checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="productType"
                        id="Forms"
                        value="Forms"
                        onChange={handleProductTypeQuery}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="Forms">Forms</label>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <input
                        className="checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="productType"
                        id="Profiles"
                        value="Profiles"
                        onChange={handleProductTypeQuery}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="Profiles">Profiles</label>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <input
                        className="checkbox"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="productType"
                        id="Landing"
                        value="Landing"
                        onChange={handleProductTypeQuery}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="Landing">Landing</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </aside>
)
```

}
Sorry for the long post! I really tried to keep it short while still trying to have it understandable If u got any question just ask!

Comment: To push multiple values for the same query param you can do `router.push({ query: { productType: ['computer', 'electronics'] } });`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:-

```
const products = ['qwery1','qqwerty2','qwerty23']


const WEB_URL = 'https://example.com'

let param  = ''
products && products.map((ele)=>{
 param = param + 'productType='+ele+'&'
})
const NEW_URL = WEB_URL+'?'+param
console.log('params',param)

let url = new URL(NEW_URL);
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);


console.log(params.getAll('productType'))
```